# Do not query against parameters that are equal to NULL in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have the following DB model in mongoose

```
Employee{
    FirstName : String,
    LastName : String,
    Job  : String,
}
```

and I have two docs that look like this:

```
{
   FirstName : Bob,
   LastName : Jackson
   Job : Professor
}

{
   FirstName : Michael,
   LastName : Jackson,
   Job : Professor,
}
```

if I have a query that does the following:

```
Employee.find{FirstName : "Michael" , LastName : NULL,  Job : NULL}
```

It will return null.

Instead I want to ignore the fields that have parameters  equal to NULL as they do not exist  in the query and the query above I wanted to be treated as :

```
Employee.find{“FirstName : Michael”}
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I just need to do something like

```
Employee.Find(FirstName : new Regex(firstNameParam,i),
LastName : new Regex(lastNameParam,i),
Job  : new Regex(jobParam,i))
```